# TypeError: iter() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm working with `xml.etree.cElementTree`, and regarding to official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) - want find element in `Element`:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, re

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML_FILE = '/cygdrive/****.csproj'

try:
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file=XML_FILE)
    root = tree.getroot()

    print type(root)

    for item in root.iter(tag='OutputPath'):
        print item.tag, item.attrib, item.text
    ....
```

But when I run it - have an error:

```
$ ./xm_par.py
<type 'Element'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xm_par.py", line 21, in <module>
    for item in root.iter(tag='OutputPath'):
TypeError: iter() takes no keyword arguments
```

What I'm miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug; the C accelerated version of the API is missing support for the `tag` parameter *as a keyword argument*. See [issue #16849](http://bugs.python.org/issue16849):

> Element.{get,iter} doesn't handle keyword arguments when using _elementtree C accelerator.

The bug was fixed in Python 3.3 and up but not in Python 2.7 yet.

You can omit the keyword and pass in the argument as a positional instead:

```
for item in root.iter('OutputPath'):
```

Demo:

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.fromstring('''\
... <root>
...     <OutputPath></OutputPath>
... </root>
... ''')
>>> tree.iter(tag='OutputPath')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: iter() takes no keyword arguments
>>> tree.iter('OutputPath')
<generator object iter at 0x1045cc5a0>
```

Comment: Thank you it is very detailed answer about `from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET`. I changed it to `from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET`.